# Is there a replacement for appengine/user in Go 1.12?

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, go

Since migrating to Go 1.12 from 1.9, appengine/user.Current() returns an empty User

Originally set this up using this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/users/

I've tried both the recommended change to use http.Request.Context() instead of appengine.NewContext() and still trying appengine.NewContext() but now calls to Current() return an empty user object (not nil, empty)

I plan on moving to a different authentication method since it's recomended to move away from the appengine package, but this was a "quick and dirty" way to secure the app for now as this only has two users (my wife and me) for the moment.

```
func getContext(r *http.Request) error {
    ctx = r.Context()
    var w http.ResponseWriter
    cu, err := Current()
        .
        .
        .
}
```

Comment: It's part of the appengine API here: https://github.com/golang/appengine/blob/master/user/user_vm.go#L17